# JavaScript concat method

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using `Array.prototype.concat()`, when I write this code:

```js
var g = [1, 11, 111];
var ga = [12, 122, 1222];
var gb = [13, 133, 1333];

var gc = g.concat(ga, [123, gb]);

console.log(gc);
```

It gives me the following result: `[1, 11, 111, 12, 122, 1222, 123, Array(3)]`

Why is `Array(3)` added to the resulting array?

Comment: What result did you expected to get?

Comment: [1,11,111,12,122,1222,123,13,133,1333]

Comment: see if[123] is not an array then why [13,133,1333] is represented as array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the values in the array is an array with three items in it and you are looking at it using a tool that gives you a summary of the data rather than a fully expanded view of it.

Answer (score 1):

`[123,gb]` does not concat arrays it's an array inside of an array, what you want is this:

```js
var g = [1,11,111];

var ga = [12,122,1222];

var gb = [13,133,1333];

var gc = g.concat(ga,[123].concat(gb));
//or better
var gc2 = g.concat(ga, 123, gb);
console.log(gc, gc2);
```

Comment: then output should be [1,11,111,12,122,122,Array(1),Array(3)] rite?

Comment: no it will be [1, 11, 111, 12, 122, 1222, 123, 13, 133, 1333]

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6 style syntax [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var g = [1,11,111];

var ga = [12,122,1222];

var gb = [13,133,1333];

var gc = [...g,...ga,123,...gb];

console.log(gc);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you!!

```js
var g = [1,11,111];

var ga = [12,122,1222];

var gb = [13,133,1333];

var gc = g.concat(ga,123,gb);

       
console.log(gc);
```